# Topic that mixes stochastic calculus and harmonic analysis.

Tags: reference-request, fourier-series, stochastic-calculus, harmonic-analysis, stochastic-integrals

Is there any topic in the current research that mixes stochastic calculus (Itô integrals, stochastic differential equations...) and harmonic analysis (Fourier series, Fourier transform, maximal operators...)?

Comment: Submartingales (resp. supermartingales) are related to subharmonic (resp. superharmonic) functions. Do you know about this?

Comment: I know that, if $\{B_t\}_{t\geq0}$ is an $n$-dimensional Brownian motion and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a $C^2$ function, then $$f(B_t)=f(0)+\int_0^t \nabla f(s)\cdot dB_s+\frac12\int_0^t \Delta f(s)\,ds,\quad\forall t\geq0.$$ Thus, if $f$ is subharmonic ($\Delta f\geq0$), then $\{f(B_t)\}_{t\geq0}$ is subharmonic; etc. But that topic belongs more to potential theory or even complex analysis, I think.

Comment: There is a course about this in Berlin that is taking place this semester: https://agnes.hu-berlin.de/lupo/rds?state=verpublish&status=init&vmfile=no&publishid=122550&moduleCall=webInfo&publishConfFile=webInfo&publishSubDir=veranstaltung They haven't placed any lecture notes online yet, but that might happen sometime in the future (if every, by August 2017). The professor teaching it (Imkeller) is one of the co-authors of this manuscript: https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~perkowsk/files/ciesielski.pdf